# CoNat : proving that 0 is neutral to the left

Tags: proof, agda, curry-howard, coinduction, codata

I am experimenting with the definition of `CoNat` taken from [this paper](https://jesper.sikanda.be/files/elaborating-dependent-copattern-matching.pdf) by Jesper Cockx and Andreas Abel:

```
open import Data.Bool
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

record CoNat : Set where
  coinductive
  field iszero : Bool
        pred : .(iszero ≡ false) -> CoNat

open CoNat public
```

I define `zero` and `plus`:

```
zero : CoNat
iszero zero = true
pred zero ()

plus : CoNat -> CoNat -> CoNat
iszero (plus m n)                                  = iszero m ∧ iszero n
pred (plus m n) _ with iszero m | inspect iszero m | iszero n | inspect iszero n
...                | false | [ p ] | _     | _     = plus (pred m p) n
...                | true  | _     | false | [ p ] = plus m (pred n p)
pred (plus _ _) () | true  | _     | true  | _
```

And I define bisimilarity:

```
record _≈_ (m n : CoNat) : Set where
  coinductive
  field
    iszero-≈ : iszero m ≡ iszero n
    pred-≈ : ∀ p q -> pred m p ≈ pred n q

open _≈_ public
```

But I am stuck with the proof that `plus zero n` is bisimilar to `n`. My guess is that in the proof I should have (at least) a with-clause for `iszero n`:

```
plus-zero-l : ∀ n -> plus zero n ≈ n
iszero-≈ (plus-zero-l _)   = refl
pred-≈ (plus-zero-l n) p q with iszero n
... | _ = ?
```

But Agda complains with to the following error message:

```
iszero n != w of type Bool
when checking that the type
(n : CoNat) (w : Bool) (p q : w ≡ false) →
(pred (plus zero n) _ | true | [ refl ] | w | [ refl ]) ≈ pred n _
of the generated with function is well-formed
```

How can I make this proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't immediately able to prove the lemma with your definition of `plus`, but here's an alternative definition that makes the proof go through:

```
open import Data.Bool
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

record CoNat : Set where
  coinductive
  field iszero : Bool
        pred : .(iszero ≡ false) -> CoNat

open CoNat public

zero : CoNat
zero .iszero = true
zero .pred ()

record _≈_ (m n : CoNat) : Set where
  coinductive
  field
    iszero-≈ : iszero m ≡ iszero n
    pred-≈ : ∀ p q → pred m p ≈ pred n q

open _≈_ public

plus′ : (n m : CoNat) → CoNat
plus′ n m .iszero = n .iszero ∧ m .iszero
plus′ n m .pred eq with n .iszero | m .iszero | n .pred | m .pred
plus′ n m .pred eq | false | _      | pn | pm = plus′ (pn refl) m
plus′ n m .pred eq | true  | false  | pn | pm = plus′ n (pm refl)
plus′ n m .pred () | true  | true   | pn | pm

plus′-zero-l : ∀ n → plus′ zero n ≈ n
plus′-zero-l n .iszero-≈ = refl
plus′-zero-l n .pred-≈ p q with n .iszero | n .pred
plus′-zero-l n .pred-≈ () _ | true  | pn
plus′-zero-l n .pred-≈ p q  | false | pn = plus′-zero-l (pn _)
```

---

FWIW, given that plus requires such an effort, I can't see this representation of conats being particularly nice to work with. You might want to consider these alternatives:

- Two mutually defined datatypes, one inductive and one coinductive, as in [*Normalization by Evaluation in the Delay Monad*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~abela/eptcs14.pdf).
- The standard library's [variation of the previous approach](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Codata/Conat.agda), which uses the `Thunk` datatype.
- `CoNat′ = ℕ ⊎ ⊤`, which is not exactly a conat but may serve similar purposes.

Comment: What is the meaning of those dotted things in the definition and proof?

Comment: @Dave They are projections written using postfix notation. `P .iszero` is the same as `iszero P`.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, but I'd like to know how to deal with my initial definition of `plus`... or is it impossible/intractable?